# How do I write a function as a binary operator?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

In my Scala program, I have a data type `Foo` and I want to write a binary operator `>>` for it.

Here's some sample code.

```
class Foo {}

object BinaryOps {
  def >>(f1: Foo, f2: Foo): Foo = ???

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f1 = new Foo()
    val f2 = new Foo()
//  val f3 = f1 >> f2   // Error: cannot resolve symbol >>
    val f4 = >>(f1, f2) // works, but I want the binary op syntax.

//  val f5 = f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4   // ultimate goal is to be able to chain calls.
  }
}
```

So far, my IDE shows me that it cannot resolve the symbol `>>`, that is, the compiler does not attempt to use it as a binary operator.

How can I change it so the symbol is found and can be used as a binary operator?

**Edit**: what if Foo cannot be changed? what if it can?

Comment: Can you modify `Foo` or not? - Also, read [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#symbolic-method-names) to be sure you really want this.

Comment: If `Foo` can be changed, then you only need to move `>>` to `Foo` `def >>(that: Foo): Foo = ???` and it will work. If `Foo` can not be changed, then you can use **extension methods** to add `>>` to `Foo` _implicitly_,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form `f1 >> f2` actually means `f1.>>(f2)` which means that `Foo` should have such a method.

```
class Foo {
  def >>(that :Foo) :Foo = ???
  ...
```

If `Foo` can't be modified you can create an implicit conversion.

```
implicit class FooOps(thisfoo :Foo) {
  def >>(thatfoo :Foo) :Foo = ???
}
```

Now `f1 >> f2` should work.